# Location API not working in Windows 7

Tags: winapi, windows-7, geolocation, sensors

My source to query the location sensors in Windows 7/8 is as follows:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

HRESULT hr              = CoInitialize(NULL);
DOUBLE latitude         = 0;
DOUBLE longitude        = 0;

if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    CComPtr<ILocation> spLocation; // This is the main Location interface

    if (SUCCEEDED(spLocation.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_Location))) // Create the Location object
    {
            // Array of report types of interest. Other ones include IID_ICivicAddressReport
        IID REPORT_TYPES[] = { IID_ILatLongReport };

        // Request permissions for this user account to receive location data for all the
        // types defined in REPORT_TYPES (which is currently just one report)
        if (FAILED(spLocation->RequestPermissions(NULL, REPORT_TYPES, ARRAYSIZE(REPORT_TYPES), TRUE))) // TRUE means a synchronous request
        {
            wprintf(L"Warning: Unable to request permissions.\n");
        }

        while (true)
        {
            // The LOCATION_REPORT_STATUS enumeration is defined in LocApi.h in the SDK
            LOCATION_REPORT_STATUS status = REPORT_NOT_SUPPORTED; 

            // Get the status of this report type
            if (SUCCEEDED(spLocation->GetReportStatus(IID_ILatLongReport, &status))) 
            {
                int error=GetLastError();

                bool fCachedData = true;
                switch (status) // If there is an error, print the error
                {
                    case REPORT_RUNNING:
                        // If the status for the current report is running, then don't print any additional message
                        fCachedData = false;
                        break;
                    case REPORT_NOT_SUPPORTED:
                        wprintf(L"\nNo devices detected.\n");
                        exit(0);
                        break;
                    case REPORT_ERROR:
                        wprintf(L"\nReport error.\n");
                        break;
                    case REPORT_ACCESS_DENIED:
                        wprintf(L"\nAccess denied to reports.\n");
                        break;
                    case REPORT_INITIALIZING:
                        wprintf(L"\nReport is initializing.\n");
                        break;
                }

                if (true == fCachedData)
                {
                    wprintf(L"The following is cached data:\n");
                }
            }

            CComPtr<ILocationReport> spLocationReport; // This is our location report object
            CComPtr<ILatLongReport> spLatLongReport; // This is our LatLong report object

            // Get the current location report,
            // then get the ILatLongReport interface from ILocationReport,
            // then ensure it isn't NULL
            if ((SUCCEEDED(spLocation->GetReport(IID_ILatLongReport, &spLocationReport))) &&
                (SUCCEEDED(spLocationReport->QueryInterface(&spLatLongReport))))
            {
                // Print the Latitude
                if (SUCCEEDED(spLatLongReport->GetLatitude(&latitude)))
                {
                    wprintf(L"Latitude: %f\n", latitude);
                }

                // Print the Longitude
                if (SUCCEEDED(spLatLongReport->GetLongitude(&longitude)))
                {
                    wprintf(L"Longitude: %f\n", longitude);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
CoUninitialize();
return 0;
}
```

I got this code from MSDN and it works fine in Windows 8. In Windows 7 I get REPORT_NOT_SUPPORTED and I'm not able to get the LAT and LONG in spite of the locationapi.dll and the lib file in Windows 7. What is wrong with the location Sensors in Windows 7? Is there an alternative to get location. The Geolocation of HTML5 gives me wrong location at times. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure that the drivers are working in Windows 7?

Comment: I could only see the drivers in the system. Many articles say that it works but in my machine it says not supported which means it doesnt. Any other way to get the location of device in Windows 7?

Comment: Get working drivers?  The location API relies on functional drivers.

Comment: it isnt working then.Is there any other way to get location? I tried getting location by IP but I don't get the correct location, it might the location of my ISP

Comment: You can get location by using the civic address.'IID REPORT_TYPES[] = { IID_ICivicAddressReport};'